# How do you use "curl" to connect to a site with a non-standard protocol?

Tags: curl, tcp, socket

This quesiton may belong on a crypto-currency forum but I'll give it a shot here.  I want to connect to a web site (mining pool) using a protocol that is not http.  I've read the protocol is "stratum+tcp".  So I quickly tried this with curl ...

```
localhost:tmp davea$ curl -U "myltcworker" -P anything 
"stratum+tcp://stratum.ltcpool.com:3333"
Enter proxy password for user 'myltcworker':
curl: (1) Protocol "stratum+tcp" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

My question is can curl be reconfigured to support this non-standard protocol or is there another command line tool I can use?

Comment: `The particular way this error message is phrased is because curl doesn't make a distinction internally of whether a particular protocol is not supported (i.e. never got any code added that knows how to speak that protocol) or if it was explicitly disabled. curl can be built to only support a given set of protocols, and the rest would then be disabled or not supported. `

Comment: Take a look at `netcat`, aka `nc`.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to [this mailing list](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2003-04/0122.html) it is not possible to rebuild curl with custom protocols.

*Stratum* protocol is also not mentioned to be en- or disabled in the section [Disabling Specific Protocols in Windows builds](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html) in its install instructions.

But have a look at [stratum-tool](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stratum-tool), maybe it satisfies your use case.

cheers